# Loading new content into UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using Storyboards and segues in my iPad app to create a popover window when the user taps "Log In". Each log in type has it's own ViewController, requiring more popover controllers.

Is it appropriate to have the main view controller generate all of the popover content, or rather replace teh content of one popover controller?

For instance (I'll try to represent this with text drawing_)

1.)
MainVC -> Popover ("Login With Email", "Log In With Facebook", etc..)
MainVC  <- User taps button
MainVC -> Popover (Email text field, Password Text field)
MainVC  <- User enters stuff...

2.)
MainVC -> Popover ("Login With Email", "Log In With Facebook", etc..)
          Popover -> Replace content (load view controller with text fields) 
                     New content -> Handler UITextField inputs

I've gone with choice 1 because it was easy to implement, although choice 2 seems more organized. What do you consider better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Either choice could work, and anything involving UI isn't a performance issue.  So the "right" answer may depend on secondary considerations like code complexity/clarity.  I vote for creating separate instances in Storyboard rather than repurposing a single instance with rutnime code.

With separate view controller setups, each scene can be laid out optimally for its content, including using dynamic constraints.  Everything is documented in the storyboard, and there is less runtime code to declutter.  To me, it's preferable to have some clutter on a storyboard than in code.  You may have different priorities.

If the ViewControllers for the different popovers share many behaviors, use inheritance to reduce code proliferation.

Comment: anything involving UI isn't a performance issue : why it is not a performance issue ?

Comment: My comment about performance was meant to say that any difference in how these approaches might perform is utterly negligible when compared to the time it takes a user to enter a key or a gesture. And Login is a "once and done" kind of action, not something done repeatedly.  Latency, of course is always a concern, and a network login shouldn't block the main thread.